# Oracle ADF web browser refresh button gets old page

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

i'm developing an ADF application. I have a problem. My Jdev version 11.1.2.3.0.

So, For example i have an URL like this "http://www.hohoho.com/view/index.xhtml?_adf.ctrl-state=ju9lnu5ld_3"

In this page i have a table gets value from DB. For example again, i changed some rows in DB browser, and clicked the web browser's refresh button. But new results doesnt get!. For example i remove the "?_adf.ctrl-state=ju9lnu5ld_3" and enter url, this gets new results. How can handle this situation. I need that when an user clicked the refresh button, last result must be fetched. I think it is based on ADF state. How can handle this situation.

Solution

Thanks Andread, mysql's autocommit property default value is true, not false :) but i was using it false. I've solved the problem like yours, but my own solution so cool :) I've only overried the clearCache() method. And it solved the problem.

```
 public void clearCache() {
        getDBTransaction().commit(); // added
        super.clearCache();
    }
```

Comment: Hello @Rahman I have a similar problem.where did you override the clearCache() method?in the managed bean of the view object?when i do that im getting a error that 'Method Clearcache not found'.is it like my managed bean should extend any class?what do i miss..kindly help..

Comment: Hi Satheesh, no in ManagedBean. You must expose your ViewObject as Java. For example your ViewObject name is CardViewObj, click the CardViewObject and open the Java Tab, click pencil icon and select Generate View Object Class : CardViewObj**Impl**. you can override clearCache() method there.

Comment: Rahman Usta I have followed the steps you have mentioned.But no use.I made sure that the clearCache() method block got executed by adding a System.out.print().But the page is not refreshed and the cache is not cleared.The view object i am using is a child of a master-child relationship object.May be is that the reason why my cache is not cleared?I also tried CacheResults = false.But it is also not working.Can you help?

Comment: @Satheesh,  overrided clearCache method only eliminates problems with Mysql isolation level strategy. You must also change CacheResults to false, in Iterator object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The results from the query are cached in the middle tier. This is the reason why updates to the database which are applied through a different channel than through your application are not reflected when the page reloads.

I am using JDeveloper 11.1.1.7. Setting the "CacheResults" property on the **Iterator** to `false` solved this issue (go to the "Bindings" tab of your page or page fragment which contains the table, select the Iterator Executable for your table data, and in the Property Inspector at the "Advanced" section, set "CacheResults" to "false").

In terms of XML, the iterator definition in the `PageDef.xml` file should look like

```
<iterator id="TestIterator" Binds="TestView1"
          DataControl="AppModuleDataControl" RangeSize="25"
          CacheResults="false"/>
```

There seem to be some additional approaches to solve this, probably this was necessary in earlier JDeveloper versions:

- http://technology.amis.nl/2012/06/18/notifying-adf-applications-of-database-changes-fast-and-lean-using-database-query-result-change-notification-part-one/
- http://radio-weblogs.com/0118231/stories/2005/06/16/whyIsntRefreshingTheBrowserPageEnoughToRefreshTheDataDisplayed.html

---

*ADDENDUM 03-DEC-2012*

OP uses MySQL. With MySQL, setting the `CacheResults` property is required, but not sufficient. By default, MySQL runs with `autocommit=false` which has the [side effect](http://ilmarkerm.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/little-side-effect-of-having-autocommit.html) of using the isolation level `REPEATABLE READ`. A `SELECT` implicitly opens a transaction, and subsequent `SELECTs` return the same result. The Oracle RDBMS uses `READ COMMITTED` by default, so that data inserted and committed in one session is returned by SELECT in a different session.

One solution to get around this in ADF is to create an implementation class for the View Object, override `executeQueryForCollection()` and commit the transaction before executing the query:

```
protected void executeQueryForCollection(Object object, Object[] object2, int i) {
    getApplicationModule().getTransaction().commit();
    super.executeQueryForCollection(object, object2, i);
}
```

Please use this carefully and review your actual isolation level requirements to make sure that you do not unintentionally commit data by a browser refresh. Another drawback of this solution is that it is not portable between Oracle RDBMS and MySQL.

See https://github.com/afester/StackOverflow/tree/master/AdfRefresh for an SSCCE.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I'm using JDeveloper 11.1.2.3.0 and "CacheResults" to "false" change didn't solve the problem.For your other URls. 1) I'm using Mysql. 2) I see this article but i couldnt find /* in overridden prepareModel() method */. Where is the prepareModel() method? How can i adapt to my Application.

Comment: Hi, using MySQL was an important information :-) Please see my updated answer about MySQL isolation levels.

Comment: Thanks Andreas, four your real answer. I've edited the post with my solution.