# adf refresh mysql auto_increment "ID" not shown until query is re-executed

Tags: java, mysql, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have a problem very similar to this question :
[Oracle ADF web browser refresh button gets old page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626438/oracle-adf-web-browser-refresh-button-gets-old-page)

My application is also running on top of a MySQL database. I have a table named IncidentType which contains 2 columns :

IncidentTypeID (int, auto_increment)
Description (varchar 60)
In my web page, I can create new records and commit them to the database. However, the IncidentTypeID will not be shown until I reload the page (via a "refresh" or close then reopen the page). Essentially, not until the VO's query is executed again on the database.

If I look at the data in the database, the IncidentTypeID is correctly assigned.

I noticed the same behaviour on the ADF Business Component tester.

What would you advice to modify to force the query to be re-executed after each commit and ?

I tried the solutions in the link above, but it didn't changed the behaviour.

I'm using jDev 11.1.2.3.0

Comment: mysql libraries tend to return the ID of newly inserted records as a return value/parameter when you do whatever your code's equivalent of `->execute($query)` is. there should be NO need to re-execute an insert query, as you'd simply be trying to create a duplicate record.

Comment: I should have been more clear, what I mean by "reexecuting the query" was the VO's Query not the Insert statement.

Answer (score 0):

See the unsupported features and "Set Up Primary Key Generation " workaround here:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/multidatabaseapp-085183.html